# NTCIP Simulator

Tags: snmp, network-protocols, snmp4j

I am writing a client application to interact with a NTCIP VMS Sign. We don't have the sign device available currently. Hence we want to develop NTCIP Sign Simulator and use it to test with our client application.

We don't have the sign yet but the sign adhers to NTCIP DMS 1203 v3 standard and we have the corresponding MIB file.

I guess I need to extend the [SNMP4J Agent](http://www.snmp4j.org/) to build the sign simulator. But not sure how to go about it.

Any idea on how to go about it please?

Answer (score 1):

Google "SNMP Simulator" for choices. Our product MIMIC Simulator is a commercial choice. The main difference in the choices is the effort to create a viable simulation, thus your decision is how much your time is worth. MIMIC ships with the NEMA NTCIP DMS 1203 MIB pre-compiled which should allow for a quick simulation.